# RSS Feader Update Interval

Tags: c#, rss

I have a feed reader running every minute (it's picking up a feed that gets updated often). But I seem to be running into getting blocked by Akamai when accessing a few websites. Perhaps they think I'm up to something, but I'm not - I just want to get the feed.

Any thoughts on how to either play nice with Akamai or code this differently? From what I know, I can't know when the feed is updated other than polling it - but is there a preferred way - like checking a cache? This is coded in c# though I doubt that makes a difference.

Comment: [Welcome to Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please explain what you tried...add some code, show examples and explain the problem. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for learn how you can improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Without more of a context it is hard to ascertain why you are being blocked. Is it because of rate limits or other access control measures?
Assuming it is rate limits, there is not much you can do. I would recommend you to first verify that the robots.txt allows you to crawl the URL and if allowed use some sort of exponential back off. Helps to play nice by providing a meaningful User-Agent so that when they do update their rules they might want to consider whitelisting legitimate requests such as yourself.

Comment: The feed site I'm accessing doesn't have a ROBOTS.TXT file. They don't seem to be on the Akamai CDN. So I don't think the feed site is reporting anything. The access issues I'm having are with other websites (like usps.com).

The only thing I can think of is that somehow running my own feed reader is triggering something with Akamai, but I've no idea how or why. So very interested if anyone else has had running a feed reader cause the problem. If I reset the IP then my access works for less than 24 hours.

Comment: USPS does have a robots file. https://www.usps.com/robots.txt. Also, if a website is not on Akamai there is not way Akamai would be responsible for blocking you. I wonder why you think so.

Comment: I appreciate your responses, but I'm not trying to access usps.com's RSS Feed. I'm accessing another site (that's the site that doesn't have a robots.txt file). I don't know if that site use Akamai. So maybe it's just bad luck that I'm getting lumped into a blacklisting of some group of IP addresses or whether it's because I'm running the feed reader. As far as I know, I'm not doing anything not allowed when polling the site's feed. It's starting to seem like I may never find out.

Comment: Why not just list out your exact issue in more detail with the specific website in question? To check whether a web property is on Akamai perform a dig command on the domain name. If it is on Akamai it will be CNAMEd to either edgesuite or edgekey.